# Shorten url of sub-folders in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll project that includes a git submodule `foobar` with some markdown files that need to be rendered in addition to the ones in the main repo. These files have paths like `./foobar/docs/current/module-1.md`.

With the current url scheme this means they get the path `/foobar/docs/current/module-1.md`, but I'd rather have the shorter path `/current/module-1.md`. Is this possible using the standard Jekyll install that comes with Github Pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [default configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) values to set [permalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) for your foobar folder.

In `_config.yml`, add :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "foobar/docs/current"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      permalink: /current/:basename
```

Comment: Thanks, but am I right in saying that the path should be corrected to `path: "foobar/docs/current"`? Otherwise I think it would be wrong, given the requirements.